# Why can't I derive the scale of DRAG pulse's Q-component by making f_{ef} vanish?

Tags: quantum-control

Say, we have a DRAG pulse that looks like $s(t):=g(t)+i\beta \dot{g}(t)$. In the frequency domain it will become $\hat{s}(\omega)=\hat{g}(\omega)-\beta\omega \hat{g}(\omega)=(1-\beta\omega)\hat{g}(\omega)$. I am tempted to set $\beta=1/\omega_{ef}$ to make the spectrum vanish at $\omega_{ef}$, the angular frequency between the excited state $e$ and its upper neighbor $f$.

But this doesn't agree with the result in the literature (e.g., Eq. 101 in [*A Quantum Engineer's Guide to Superconducting Qubits*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.06560)), where the scale of the Q component is $\lambda/\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the anharmonicity. What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question: I forgot the modulation. After putting it back, we will have

$$\hat{s}(\omega)=(1-\beta(\omega-\omega_c))\hat{g}(\omega-\omega_c)\Longrightarrow\beta=1/(\omega_{ef}-\omega_c)$$

When there is no detuning, the carrier frequency $\omega_c=\omega_{ge}$ and $\beta=1/\alpha$, agreeing with the DRAG scale that minimizes the leakage.